# Context value for the variable {{ media }} in django views

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

There is a {{ media }} variable used in some of the django admin templates. ***delete_confirmation.html***, ***change_form.html*** , and ***delete_selected_confirmation.html*** . This variable adds several javascript files including jQuery library to the templates.

I want to know what is the value passed to the context variable in the views that call those templates.

My purpose is to use the same javascript files in the templates that I create for the custom views in the django admin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I am customizing the Django admin, it is not any view but the ModelAdmin, that needs to pass the context. I got the answer from django.contrib.admin.options.py. It has the property `media` which contains the list of javascript files and returns the HTML code to include those files in the template.

Access it using `self.media` and pass it to the template.